# Is there a query parameter to change facebook profile image size?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Until recently i've used Facebook graph request to get user's profile picture. I would get a response like

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t5/49852_1127262413_1077_q.jpg
```

Now i've changed it to get a better resolution picture. Problem is that I have all the previous user that I now need to get new pictures for, I would have like to just change the url to include the new size like :

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/t5/49852_1127262413_1077_q.jpg?size=600
```

Is there any way to do that ? Or would I have to make new requests to server to get new pictures ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript sdk, you can get the profile picture of the current user by following. User has to grant permission to your application and you should also have initiate Javascript-sdk

```
FB.api('/me/picture', function(response) {
    // response.data.url is the url to the photo                                
});
```

To change the size, give additional parameters height and width. change the values for the parameters to get the desired size. Also, instead of "me", you can provide Facebook user id

```
me/picture?&height=200&width=200
```

Please see this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i've asked. I already know how to request the right size. Was wondering if I could somehow manipulate the url to show me a different size without requesting a new url.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a sign anywhere that you can get different sizes by adding query parameters to the picture link url.

That's a real shame, lots of other apis offer this capability (Google+ api for example)

Anyway, the answer is

```
NO
```